# assertContains() url: testing best practice

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Have a test for emails that works. However, before I added the string url I was getting this error: Failed asserting that 'TESTCODE1234' contains "http://bidbird.test/invitations/TESTCODE1234".

How would you improve the url comparison for elegance?

```
    /** @test**/
    public function email_contains_a_link_to_accept_the_invitation()
    {
            // test stuff...
            $this->assertContains(url('/invitations/TESTCODE1234'), "http://bidbird.test/invitations/{$mail->invitation->invitation_code}");

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
$url = 'http://bidbird.test/invitations/{$mail->invitation->invitation_code}';

$this->assertContains('TESTCODE1234', $url);
```

As an alternative you can use a regex check for the given string

`$this->assertRegexp('/TESTCODE1234/', $url);`

Comment: thank you. Never thought of using a regex!


phpunit was upset, so adding double quotes allowed this to pass . vs. single quotes. $url = "http://bidbird.test/invitations/{$mail->invitation->invitation_code}";

Comment: Yeah, of course, that should have been double quotes :see_no_evil:
@errantries